# How to check if cell table in word contains bookmark?

Tags: vba, ms-word, cell, bookmarks

I want to check if a table cell contains a bookmark, if so, get the name of that bookmark.
I used the method
`Selection.Cells(1).Range.Bookmarks.Count`
But the result is not correct, all cells in the same row return the same value, even though only 1 cell contains the bookmark.

However, when using `Selection.Cells(1).Range.BookmarkID` to check, only cells containing bookmarks will have a value of non-zero, cells without bookmarks will have a value of 0.
So I don't know how to determine the cell containing the bookmark.

I create a table with 3 rows and 5 columns and insert 3 bookmarks in column 2 and try the following test

```
Sub GetNameBookmark()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        For j = 1 To 5
            Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(i).Cells(j).Range.BookmarkID & _
            ":" & ActiveDocument.Tables(2).Rows(i).Cells(j).Range.Bookmarks(1).Name
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Print results:

0:BM01
1:BM01
0:BM01
0:BM01
0:BM01

0:BM02
2:BM02
0:BM02
0:BM02
0:BM02

0:BM03
3:BM03
0:BM03
0:BM03
0:BM03

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward:

```
Sub GetNameBookmark()    
    With Selection.Cells(1).Range
        If .BookmarkID > 0 Then Debug.Print .Bookmarks(1).Name
    End With
End Sub
```